# HTML, CSS - div in div color

Tags: html, css

I want that every second line is grey. It works almost, but on the left and the right side, there are a few Pixels white.

Does anybody knows why?

HTML

```
<div class="recent">
    <h1>Recent Downloads:</h1>
    <div class="row">test</div>
    <div class="row">test</div>
    <div class="row">test</div>
    <div class="row">test</div>
    <div class="row">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.recent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30%;
    width: 35%;

background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}

.recent h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
    background-color: white;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8drX/4/

Comment: You use white borders for your `.recent` class ...

Comment: Remove the height from the `.recent` div? The contents are overflowing. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/C8drX/8/

Comment: You can also use Bootstrap :)

Comment: How is Bootstrap helpful here? It's not relevant to the situation.

Comment: Bootsrap have already in default (I mean, you do not have to code it), evry second line in color (grey)

Comment: But that's not the problem. The row colors are fine. This is an overflow issue.

Comment: I did not answer like it is solution, it is sugestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove borders from `.recent`:

```
.recent {
    border: 0px;
}
```

and maybe add some padding to `.row`:

```
.row {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8drX/6/)

Answer (score 2):

The height of the .recent div is to small. The way I see it, you can do one of four things:

1. Remove the height property from .recent
2. increase the height property on .recent
3. remove a child div from the .recent-div
4. Like Wil93 sugested, you can remove borders from .recent and add padding to .row

Here is a fiddle where I just removed the height all together:

(`/*height:30%;*/`)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/C8drX/10/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set

```
border-color: white;
```

in

```
.recent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30%;
    width: 35%;

    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Check **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8drX/7/)** you will understand

You can simply remove it using

```
border:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use this, replacing the current css rules:

```
background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .recent div has a border from your user agent stylesheet because you're setting a border-style. Set it to 0 and use padding in your .row divs instead.